# How to get indexes of top 2 values of each row in a 2-D numpy array, but with a specific area is excluded?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2-D array for example:

```
p = np.array([[21,2,3,1,12,13],
             [4,5,6,14,15,16],
             [7,8,9,17,18,19]])
b = np.argpartition(p, np.argmin(p, axis=1))[:, -2:]  
com = np.ones([3,6],dtype=np.int)
com[np.arange(com.shape[0])[:,None],b] = 0
print(com)
```

b is the indices of top 2 values of each row in p:

```
b = [[0 5]
    [4 5]
    [4 5]]
```

com is np.ones matrix, the same size as p, the element whose index is same as b will change to 0.

So the result is :

```
com = [[0 1 1 1 1 0]
       [1 1 1 1 0 0]
       [1 1 1 1 0 0]]
```

Now I have one more constraint :

```
p[0:2,0:2] = [[21  2]
              [4  5]]
```

The numbers in these area [0:2,0:2] should not be considered, so the result should be:

```
b = [[4 5]
     [4 5]
     [4 5]]
com = [[1 1 1 1 0 0]
       [1 1 1 1 0 0]
       [1 1 1 1 0 0]]
```

How can I do this ? Should I use a mask or something similarly?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the values in those slices to a low value, ensuring that they won't be among the two largest, an *then* use `argpartition`:

```
out = np.copy(p)
out[0:2,0:2] = -np.inf
np.argpartition(out, [-2,-1])[:, -2:] 

array([[4, 5],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 5]])
```

Comment: Thank you again, yatu ! I'm just like a stupid student and bother you twice.  It's a smart method ~

Comment: Thank you yatu :)). I'm a new user in stack overflow. Thanks  for your help! I'm also trying  to learn stuff about being a data scientist, I will follow you :))@yatu